# Show with a blond male teen, a big older guy and a magic girl who travelled on a huge cat

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I was watching a show around 2012. There was this blond teen (*I am pretty sure he's a teen*) who was a snooty prince who only wore different shades of light blue, blue, and dark blue, and there were two other people. One was this massive tank of a man (*much older than the prince*) and he would only wear different shades of red. There was also this girl who could do magic. And I remember a line of hers being, *"Birds of a feather stick together!"* when weird bat things were attacking them. And last, they had this huge cat animal thing that they would use to get around.

For some reason I remember one episode, in particular, the plot being one where the antagonists (*in disguise*) convinced the others that the Prince wasn't a Prince and that it was a mix up with this other dude, who looked practically like the Prince but with brown hair. The whole episode was him getting humiliated, and shrugged aside until the end where the antagonists were foiled and the group went about on their merry way.

The art style was lineless and pretty blocky.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  What language was it in?

Comment: @DavidW  I watched it when I was around 5, and it was in English

Comment: But what year were you 5?  We have no idea how old you are (and you don't need to tell us); what we need to know is what year this was played.

Comment: it was 2012 or 2013

Comment: Sounds vaguely like some iteration of He-Man and the Masters of the Universe, but doesn't he ride the giant cat while accompanied by Man-at-Arms?

Comment: Really sounds like He-Man, though it sounds like one of the older series.

Comment: it's not He-Man

Comment: The prince was a twink